# Convert a DataFrame with a list of JSONs column into a JSON

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a .csv file in chunks, and convert those chunks into a JSON. The problem is, that the csv has a column which is a list of json objects (`replies` in this case):

```
_id,title,description,count,replies
859f41bd,thr,hrt,5,[]
2816b949,fasd,asdf,2,[{'id': '1e8djah', 'description': 'hey'}]
```

When I do

```
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(FILE_NAME, chunksize=BATCH_SIZE):
        chunk_to_json = pd.DataFrame.to_json(chunk, orient='records')
```

`chunk_to_json` has the list of replies as a string, instead of a list:

```
"replies":"[{'id': '1e8djah', 'description': 'hey'}]"
```

Although I see the column type is an `object` when I do `dtypes`. And doing `chunk['replies'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x))` returns the error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`. I want the output to be:

```
"replies": [{'id': '1e8djah', 'description': 'hey'}]
```

Is it possible to easily parse this?
I also have the option to modify how I put the data into the .csv. I use pandas' `to_json` to put the `replies` inside the csv, so the double quotes requirement issue seems strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes are no valid JSON. You can simply replace the single quote by double quotes:

```
import json

input_string = "[{'id': '1e8djah', 'description': 'hey'}]"
input_string = input_string.replace("\'", "\"")

result = json.loads(input_string)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '1e8djah', 'description': 'hey'}]
```

Comment: I see. There was a mistake in the .csv creator then. Is it possible to put a list of JSONs in a field in a csv directly? Or do I have to put it in as a string (with quotes) and then parse it back to a JSON when I read the csv? All of the pandas methods seem to wrap the list in quotes.

Comment: Could it be that you get the JSON, parse it to a dictionary and then store it in the dataframe? Then the single quotes would be correctly generated as you do not store a JSON, but a dictionary.